# Is FindFirst,FindNext & FindClose Thread safe in delphi

Tags: delphi

Is FindFirst,FindNext & FindClose Thread safe in delphi ?
If not what should be used in there place ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FindFirst, FindNext & FindClose use API calls and they are Thread safe.
Every thread must use its own API handle for file access.

Comment: Yes you right but use API calls and all local variables are stored on the stack except TSearchRec. So if you don't share the TSearchRec between threads it is Thread safe.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use a shared TSearchRec variable the routines are thread safe.